# How to force a set of possible values in conditional aggregation?

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I have a query that uses conditional aggregation to display totals.
See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab1915/2

```
select ts.description,
sum(case when ta.group_number = 1 then 1 else 0 end) group_one
,sum(case when ta.group_number = 2 then 1 else 0 end) group_two
,sum(case when ta.group_number = 3 then 1 else 0 end) group_three
from ta 
join ts on ta.status_id=ts.status_id
group by ts.description;
```

However, I need the results to also show another row for the status "cancelled", which is not currently showed because there are not any record with that status, but I need to display "cancelled" with 0 counts anyway,
Any idea how I would do that?

The DDL for this example is

```
create table ta (group_number number, status_id number);
create table ts (status_id number, description varchar(111));
insert into ta (group_number,status_id) values (1,1);
insert into ta (group_number,status_id) values (2,1);
insert into ta (group_number,status_id) values (3,2);
insert into ta (group_number,status_id) values (3,3);
insert into ta (group_number,status_id) values (3,3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join so you pick up all of the `ts` valueswhich means you need to reverse the order of the tables; and I'd use `count()` instead of `sum()`:

```
select ts.description,
count(case when ta.group_number = 1 then 1 end) group_one
,count(case when ta.group_number = 2 then 1 end) group_two
,count(case when ta.group_number = 3 then 1 end) group_three
,count(case when ta.group_number = 4 then 1 end) group_four
from ts 
left join ta on ta.status_id=ts.status_id
group by ts.description;

DESCRIPTION           GROUP_ONE  GROUP_TWO GROUP_THREE
-------------------- ---------- ---------- -----------
started                       1          1           0
finished                      0          0           2
cancelled                     0          0           0
progressing                   0          0           1
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab1915/5)

The case expression can evaluate to anything when matched, it just has to be non-null. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COUNT.html):

> If you specify *`expr`*, then `COUNT` returns the number of rows where *`expr`* is not null.

so where the case is *not* matched it evaluates to null, which is not counted. (You can have `else null` if you prefer to be explicit, but I tend to prefer brevity...)